# Flux.jl doesn't utilize all the available threads for machine learning in julia

Tags: performance, tensorflow, julia, flux.jl

I ran a benchmark test on the below mentioned flux code which is taken from [model-zoo](https://github.com/FluxML/model-zoo/blob/master/vision/cifar10/cifar10.jl). I have noticed few performance issues:

1. Flux is slower than python equivalent.
2. Flux doesn't utilize all the threads for execution (usually the CPU usage is about 50%).

**Code:**

```
#model
using Flux
vgg19() = Chain(            
    Conv((3, 3), 3 => 64, relu, pad=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1)),
    Conv((3, 3), 64 => 64, relu, pad=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1)),
    MaxPool((2,2)),
    Conv((3, 3), 64 => 128, relu, pad=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1)),
    Conv((3, 3), 128 => 128, relu, pad=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1)),
    MaxPool((2,2)),
    Conv((3, 3), 128 => 256, relu, pad=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1)),
    Conv((3, 3), 256 => 256, relu, pad=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1)),
    Conv((3, 3), 256 => 256, relu, pad=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1)),
    MaxPool((2,2)),
    Conv((3, 3), 256 => 512, relu, pad=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1)),
    Conv((3, 3), 512 => 512, relu, pad=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1)),
    Conv((3, 3), 512 => 512, relu, pad=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1)),
    MaxPool((2,2)),
    Conv((3, 3), 512 => 512, relu, pad=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1)),
    Conv((3, 3), 512 => 512, relu, pad=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1)),
    Conv((3, 3), 512 => 512, relu, pad=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1)),
    BatchNorm(512),
    MaxPool((2,2)),
    flatten,
    Dense(512, 4096, relu),
    Dropout(0.5),
    Dense(4096, 4096, relu),
    Dropout(0.5),
    Dense(4096, 10),
    softmax
)

#data

using MLDatasets: CIFAR10
using Flux: onehotbatch
# Data comes pre-normalized in Julia
trainX, trainY = CIFAR10.traindata(Float32)
testX, testY = CIFAR10.testdata(Float32)
# One hot encode labels
trainY = onehotbatch(trainY, 0:9)
testY = onehotbatch(testY, 0:9)

#training

using Flux: crossentropy, @epochs
using Flux.Data: DataLoader
model = vgg19()
opt = Momentum(.001, .9)
loss(x, y) = crossentropy(model(x), y)
data = DataLoader(trainX, trainY, batchsize=64)
@epochs 100 Flux.train!(loss, params(model), data, opt)
```

I have tried running this code with `sysimage` including `pre-compilation` file, however the results were still not in favor of flux.

Please comment on my mistake in this code which is making it slower than python. As i was wondering the julia is supposed to be faster than python.

I have also posted this question on [julia-discourse](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/why-is-flux-model-slower-than-python/54154).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: x-ref: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/why-is-flux-model-slower-than-python/54154/3

Comment: It is worth mentioning that most of the high performance libraries in python are written in c language and use python only as a kind of interface. So you should be careful on your expectation like "julia is supposed to be faster than this because this is python". Sometimes you will be comparing a c implementation against a julia one.

Comment: You need to start Julia with the parameter `-t nThreads`. See https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/multi-threading/. Using Juno this should have been done automatically.

Comment: @crstnbr thanks for listing the reference, you may click on `julia-discourse` hyperlink in my article to reach there too.

Comment: @aramirezreyes thanks for the feedback. 
I see, you are right as listed by community on the discourse, tensorflow is written in C++ and using python as front end while flux is in julia. This means i am technically comparing julia to C++.

Comment: @Antonello thanks for the feedback, i started julia with multithreading, i even created the system image to reduce the loading and compilation time but still the timings were quite high (almost double).